# PostgreSQL - Empty table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called EVENTS on my PostgreSQL DB schema.
It is empty, i.e. when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS
```

I get an empty results set.

Nonetheless, the table occupies 5MB of disk space.
I'm executing

```
SELECT round(pg_total_relation_size('events') / 1024.0 / 1024.0, 2)
```

And I'm getting 5.13MB.

I tried to explicitly run VACUUM, but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Truncate the table:

```
truncate events;
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html)

> TRUNCATE quickly removes all rows from a set of tables. It has the same effect as an unqualified DELETE on each table, but since it does not actually scan the tables it is faster. Furthermore, it reclaims disk space immediately, rather than requiring a subsequent VACUUM operation. This is most useful on large tables.

If you want to immediately reclaim disk space keeping existing rows of a non-empty table, you can use [vacuum:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html)

```
vacuum full events;
```

This locks exclusively the table and rewrite it (in fact, creates a new copy and drops the old one). It is an expensive operation and generally not recommended on larger tables.

In RDBMS some redundant usage of the disk space is a normal state. If you have a properly configured [autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) the unused space will be used when new rows are inserted.

Comment: Nice :) Is there a way to truncate the entire schema?

Comment: and is there anythings I need to consider when doing that? is it costly?

Comment: `Truncate table` is faster (especially on large tables) than `delete from table` and has no side effects (other than that it reclaims disk space immediately). Unfortunately, a schema can not be truncated.

Comment: So truncate removes the entire table. But is there a way to claim disk space and keeping existing rows if they exist?

Comment: `vacuum full table` locks exclusively the table and rewrite it (in fact, creates a new copy and drops the old one). It is expensive operation and generally not recommended. In RDBMS some redundant usage of the disk space is a normal state. The unused space will be used when new rows are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have dead rows or bloat in your table, VACUUM will not actually reclaim its memory but make it reusable and this is used when you insert data to the table next time.

To reclaim the memory used, try

VACUUM FULL events;