# why postgres table size increase after update TEXT column from long log text to empty string increases?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I have a table with a `TEXT` field `not null` that contains logs.

After updating all records older than X to an empty string ``, when I compare `select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('my_table'));` before and after the update, the table size actually increased a bit.

PS: the table have 880k rows and 511k rows were updated to `""`. Also, this field isn't part of index.

Comment: Why not set to `NULL` instead, or even try deleting them? You'll have to change your schema definition.

Comment: Each update inserts a new row and makes the old one invisible. Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415048/1995738) about unused disk space.

Comment: I can't delete the rows as it has more information that still relevant. I was just trying to reduce table size without changing table structure. I know changing to `NULL` should be better or maybe even creating a separate table only to hold this column and making a `FK`(then I could delete these instances). But shouldn't updating to an empty string reduce size as well?

Comment: Try vacuuming the table and see if it reduces in size.

Comment: @tadman NULL means "unknown", which doesn't seem to be a good fit here.

Comment: @edruid `VACUUM` normally does not reduce the size of a table significantly, it just makes the space reusable.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It also means "undefined" which is the case here.

Comment: @tadman An empty string is not undefined at all. I don't want to be fascist here, it is just my experience that abusing NULL often leads to complicated and inefficient queries.

Comment: Thanks @klin for your answer: "Each update inserts a new row and makes the old one invisible" explains why one of my tables keeps increasing its size a lot each time I run UPDATE even when rows values are not changing: if anyone else was looking for that, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69464/postgres-table-growing-on-massive-updates or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY